Mui Slider - Value Label align to sides
I am trying to sort out an issue with Mui Slider.
Currently I have this:

but the idea is for the label to align with left and right side, i.e. not to go over the edge.

I have tried to position this with margin-right but this doesn't work if the max value changes dynamically, meaning i would have to change the margin based on how big the value is.
Any ideas?
playcode.io

It's gonna look the same, just make slider smaller
